# CSS: sub menu alignment and styling (Strictly CSS; without javascript)

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get my first menu to work. I got the basics off of [CSS Menu without javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4873604/css-menu-without-javascript) . I am trying to make it as simple as possible. I got to look close to what I want it to look (Not exactly what I REALLY want it to look like):

http://jsfiddle.net/EjXgU/2/

The main problem is submenus. They stack one below the other instead to the right of the parent menu. Also, the first level of submenus do not stack right below the line on the main menu, but within it.

Another problem I was able to notice, I want to add an rgba `background-color` (transparency). However, for every submenu level, the transparency changes.

I also accept any css3 tips to make it look "flashy" and fancy =)

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Title: css-menu-without-javascript</title>
</head>
<body>

    <nav>
        <ul id="menu">
        <li><a href="#" title="Home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="normaltip" title="Units">With sub-menus --&gt;</a>
            <ul class="submenu">
            <li><a href="...">Submenu 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="...">Submenu 2 --&gt;</a>
                <ul class="submenu">
                <li><a href="...">Sub-submenu 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="...">Sub-submenu 2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#" title="Future Residents">Menu item 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" title="Current Residents">With sub-menus --&gt;</a>
            <ul class="submenu">
            <li><a href="...">Submenu 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="...">Submenu 4 --&gt;</a>
                <ul class="submenu">
                <li><a href="...">Sub-submenu 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="...">Sub-submenu 4 --&gt;</a>
                    <ul class="submenu">
                    <li><a href="...">Sub-sub-submenu 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="...">Sub-sub-submenu 2</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#" title="Contact Us">Menu item 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
/*https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4873604/css-menu-without-javascript*/
#menu li>ul { display: none; }
#menu li:hover>ul { display: block; }
/*End of Nathan MacInnes' code*/


nav { position: relative; }
#menu> li { float: left; padding:10px; border: 1px ridge #cccccc;}
#menu a {
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size: 20px;
    color:#191919;
    padding:10px;
}
.submenu { background-color: rgba( 0,0,0,0.5 ); }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're wanting CSS-only drop-down menus, then check out [Son of Suckerfish](http://www.htmldog.com/articles/suckerfish/dropdowns/). It's pretty much the de facto way of achieving such.

There *is* a bit on using JavaScript to get around earlier version of Internet Explorer's lack of support for pseudo elements, but I think this is IE7 and below, so can probably be dropped, depending on what level of support you're wanting to have for older browsers such as IE < 7. Other browsers (Firefox, Chrome, Safari, Opera etc) will display the menu and function just fine with the CSS only.

Answer (score 1):

You could try

```
.submenu { background-color: rgba( 0,0,0,0.25 );
    margin-left: 25px;}
```

The transparency value is additive — a submenu within a submenu gets that added twice, so a second submenu will be less transparent. Starting with a lower value allows that to be useful.

Adding the margin displaces the text to the right, and I rather like the way each submenu "embraces" its own children.

http://jsfiddle.net/EjXgU/3/